# SourceCharacter in ECMAScript 5.1

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm reading the [ECMAScript Specification 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) but there is a point that it is not pretty clear, in my opinion.

In Section 6 - Source Text the specification declares a source character as follow:

```
SourceCharacter::
    any Unicode code unit
```

and after it says:

> Throughout the rest of this document, the phrase "code unit" and the word "character" will be used to refer to a 16-bit unsigned value used to represent a single 16-bit unit of text. The phrase "Unicode character" will be used to refer to the abstract linguistic or typographical unit represented by a single Unicode scalar value (which may be longer than 16 bits and thus may be represented by more than one code unit).

I think that this sentence it's a bit ambiguous because someone (as me initially) can think that the only allowed characters are those between 0-65535 of the Unicode table.

So, is the sentence ambiguous or only characters between 0-65536 can be used?

Comment: Good question. As you might know, original JavaScript Unicode support was basically broken because it was based in the wrong assumption that UTF-16 is a fixed size encoding. I've heard there've been improvements but everything needs to be backwards-compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is intentional, they're telling you that any code unit is allowed and then saying that for clarify *after* the definition of source character they typically mean code unit rather than character.

Note that in UTF16 a code *unit* is different from a code *point*.

Everything is a code unit which is 16 bit, but code *points* can be composed from several code units.

For example "" is a single UTF16 code *point* but it is two *code units*.

```
"".charCodeAt(0) // 55357
"".charCodeAt(1) // 56589
```

Comment: I think the problem is they are mixing word "unicode" with "code unit". Unicode maps characters to numbers, how many bytes are used to represent these numbers depends on the encoding.

Comment: @welcome nothing is mixed nor is anything ambiguous. Unicode in that context is explicitly UTF16. Note that _identifiers_ outside of literals must be two byte code points (that are also a single code unit) - but that's not really what you asked.

Comment: So, if UTF-16 can represent every unicode character using code units, what's the difference between saying "any unicode code point" and "any unicode code unit"?

Comment: Some code points require several code units - for example the poop emoji - this is called a _surrogate pair_. UTF16 is quirky :D

Comment: So does this mean I can't used characters outside the 0-65535 range? can I use the poop emoji in a JavaScript script?

Comment: @welcome yes, you can - a SourceCharacter is a single source unit but you can use multiple code units for a code point. You can use a poop emoji in a _string literal_ (from the spec PoV it's two code "characters" but so what?) for example. You can't name your variable poop emoji (but you can name it lambda sign or Hebrew aleph) - since poop emoji is two code units and VariableDeclaration works like that. 
Quirky, in practice it means you can use that character range - but not name actual code entities the same way. Python 2, PHP, Java and most other languages are pretty similar in this regard.